# Post to Django rest framework API but always get a 'This field is required' error

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django rest framework 3.2.1, the `GET` is perfect, but `POST` does not work.

This is the Model:

```
class Sample(models.Model):
    ownerBuilding = models.ForeignKey(Building)
    coordinateX = models.IntegerField(default=0, help_text='X coordinate for this sampling point located in a building')
    coordinateY = models.IntegerField(default=0, help_text='Y coordinate for this sampling point located in a building')
    creation_Time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True,
                               help_text='additional description for this sample point.')

class Meta:
    unique_together = ('ownerBuilding', 'coordinateX','coordinateY')

def __str__(self):
    return "Sample for building " + str(self.ownerBuilding)
```

The Serializer:

```
class SampleSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    ownerBuilding = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(many=False, read_only=True, view_name='building-detail')

class Meta:
    model = Sample
    fields = ('url', 'ownerBuilding', 'coordinateX', 'coordinateY', 'creation_Time','description')
```

The View:

```
class SampleList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Sample.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SampleSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, IsTechniciansGroupOrReadOnly,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Sample.objects.all()
        ownerBuildingId = self.request.query_params.get('ownerBuildingId', None)

        if ownerBuildingId is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(ownerBuilding=ownerBuildingId)

        return queryset
```

When I test the `POST` to this API with data:

```
{"ownerBuilding":"http://rest.xxxxxxxx.xyz:8090/buildings/1/","coordinateX":33,"coordinateY":44,"description":"5dfadfasdfsadf5"}
```

I always get this error:

```
{
    "ownerBuilding": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

anyone could help?

the `http://rest.xxxxxxxx.xyz:8090/buildings/1/` exists.

[edit0]:
if I `POST` with:

```
{"coordinateX":33,"coordinateY":44,"description":"5dfadfasdfsadf5"}
```

I still get the same result.

Comment: Posting without `ownerBuilding` will not help, it is still required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serializer fields are [required by default](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#core-arguments).

Also, DRF `ModelSerializer` (and `HyperlinkedModelSerializer`) adds `UniqueTogetherValidator`s for all model's `unique_together` constraints. This implicitly makes all fields in the constraint required, with exception for fields for which defaults are set. See [doc](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#uniquetogethervalidator).

`ownerBuilding` is read only on the serializer:

```
ownerBuilding = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(many=False, \
                            read_only=True, view_name='building-detail')
```

but you don't provide a defualt nor set the value manually, so this field is treated as empty, hence the error message.

Either remove the `read_only` or set a default.