# HyperlinkedRelatedField required=False not working

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

It seems no matter what I do I cannot get the `parent` field to not be required. I'm using DRF version 3.2.3 and Django 1.8.4.

Model definition of field:

```
parent = models.ForeignKey(
    "self", verbose_name=_("Parent"), blank=True, null=True,
    default=None, related_name='children')
```

The model also has a `unique_together`:

```
unique_together = (('owner', 'parent', 'name',),)
```

Serializer definition of field:

```
parent = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
    view_name='category-detail', queryset=Category.objects.all(),
    required=False)
```

I'm writing unittests and the response code is 400 with a text response of:

```
{'parent': [u'This field is required.']}
```

The `parent` field is a ForeignKey back to another row in the same table.

Gals/Guys any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: I have a version: sometimes a field can be implicitly made `required` by some other piece of code. One case I encountered is the model-level `unique_together` constraint, that makes all included fields required on the serializer level. Is this your case maybe?

Comment: Ivan, never thought of that and yes it is in my `unique_together` constraint, but it can be NULL even if it's in the constraint. I created an object through the admin with `parent` NULL and it worked. However, this doesn't work in the serializer. It wants a `Category` object and won't allow a NULL/None.

Comment: I think you will just have to override the serializer `save` or viewset `create/update` to set the value to what you want at this point. Another option is to try to remove the [`UniqueTogetherValidator`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#uniquetogethervalidator) from the serializer's validators in its init. On the other hand I think it is added for a reason.

Comment: See note in the `UniqueTogetherValidator` doc.

Comment: This worked with admin because it uses `ModelForm`, which is another thing entirely and which handles the validation in its own way.

Comment: Could you please modify the model code to include the `unique_together` constraint?

Comment: Also, a clarification: it is `UniqueTogetherValidator` that does not allow `None`s not the constraint itself.

Comment: I've been looking at the `UniqueTogetherValidator` code and I can see that. I think what I need to do is override the validator with my version that will allow whatever value is in the `default` value in the model to be allowed. I'm beginning to feel this is a bug in the validator, because it says it will allow a value in the `default` if it's there, but doesn't in the case that value is None.

Comment: I will link to my answer to a similar question. I would mark as duplicate, but that one's author did not accept the answer so I can't.

Comment: See this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33098107).

Comment: Ah, the `default` mentioned is on the `HyperlinkedRelatedField` field not on the model field. That solved my problem. It now works as expected without writing my own Validator. Ivan, you should create an answer mentioning all the facts and I'll accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes a field can be implicitly made `required` by some other piece of code. One case I encountered is the model-level `unique_together` constraint, that makes all included fields required on the serializer level. From the [doc](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#uniquetogethervalidator):

> **Note**: The `UniqueTogetherValidation` class always imposes an implicit constraint that all the fields it applies to are always
>   treated as required. Fields with default values are an exception to
>   this as they always supply a value even when omitted from user input.

I think you will just have to override the serializer `save` or viewset `create/update` to set the value to what you want at this point. Another option is to try to remove the `UniqueTogetherValidator` from the serializer's validators in its `__init__`. On the other hand I think it is added for a reason.

It is worth mentioning that in admin and anywhere else `ModelForm` is used, these fields won't be required because `ModelForm` is another thing entirely and it handles the validation in its own way.